# Google sheets - copy adjacent cells if value is identical

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a table like this

| Letter | Selected letter | Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| B | D | 2 |
| C |  | 3 |
| D |  | 4 |

I'd like to have as a result:

| Selected letter | Number |
| --- | --- |
| B | 1 |
| D | 4 |

I tried to compare the two firsts columns to retrieve the third one with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

With the table of key-number pairs in columns `A2:A` and `C2:C`, you can look up the keys in column `B2:B` with this formula in cell `D2`:

```
=arrayformula( iferror( vlookup(B2:B, A2:C, columns(A2:C), false) ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

[FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function combined with [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) will work

```
=FILTER({A2:A,C2:C},COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A))
```